# Does Cloud Dataflow streaming workers get the Sustained Usage Discount?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

On the old pricing page they mention that all the Google Compute instances used by Cloud Dataflow workers are billed based on sustained use price rules, but the new pricing page does not mention it anymore.

I asume that since internally it is using the same Compute instances, the discount should probably apply, but since I couldn't find any mention of it anywhere, I would appreciate if anyone is able to confirm this.

[Old Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing-old)

[New Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new pricing model there is no sustained use discount.